# Dynamically change the name of the resource file to be used?

Tags: android

It is possible to do something like:

```
if (colorScheme == 1)
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button + "_1")
```

in order to use R.drawable.button_1 as the resource for this button in color scheme 1, if there are files named button_1.png, button_2.png, button_3.png in drawable folder.
(dynamically use different resource file for the same UI element based on the color scheme being used?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something simular using getIdentifier():

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("button_1","drawable",context.getPackageName());
button.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

Comment: That's a great idea! But do you know how could I do the same thing in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to be dynamic, there will be some code required.  You can set up your layout in xml  Like this:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

And then reference it in your code like this:

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("button_1","drawable",context.getPackageName());
Button button = (Button view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

I haven't tested this, but this should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Put `R.drawable.button_n` in an array `int res[]` and then call them by `button.setBackgroundResource(res[i])`